# HttpURLConnection spawns a large number of processes?

Tags: java, http

I have some rather basic code to fetch the HTTP status code from a given URL:

```
URL url = new URL(args[0]);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

int code = connection.getResponseCode();
connection.disconnect();

System.out.print(code);
System.exit(0);
```

Obviously everything is within try/catch blocks, but all they do is exit with an error. The code seemed to work, so I ran a list of URLs against it. I monitored processes and noticed that on some of the URLs, about 10 Java instances for the same URL were spawned.

In other words, I would run:

```
java -jar HTTP.jar {URL}
```

and see that command about 10 times when I ran htop. They look like regular processes, not threads, and in htop I have "hide userland threads" turned on. What is going on? Are multiple requests being sent or just one?

Answer (score 0):

You've inadvertently run the command multiple times. This can happen if you fail to escape `&` in a URL in a shell command. Bash interprets the `&` character as meaning "run this command in the background", and you get the shell prompt back, but your process is still running.

Put the URL in single quotes and you won't have the problem.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. None of the URLs I'm testing have & in the URL. This only seems to happen when the page takes a long time to load. I created a PHP page which waits 5 seconds before outputting anything, and that seems to trigger the multiple processes.